# Spark Dataset and java.sql.Date

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-encoders

Let's say I have a Spark `Dataset` like this:

```
scala> import java.sql.Date
scala> case class Event(id: Int, date: Date, name: String)
scala> val ds = Seq(Event(1, Date.valueOf("2016-08-01"), "ev1"), Event(2, Date.valueOf("2018-08-02"), "ev2")).toDS
```

I want to create a new `Dataset` with only the name and date fields. As far as I can see, I can either use `ds.select()` with `TypedColumn` or I can use `ds.select()` with `Column` and then convert the `DataFrame` to `Dataset`.

However, I can't get the former option working with the `Date` type. For example:

```
scala> ds.select($"name".as[String], $"date".as[Date])
<console>:31: error: Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
              ds.select($"name".as[String], $"date".as[Date])
                                                      ^
```

The later option works:

```
scala> ds.select($"name", $"date").as[(String, Date)]
res2: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(String, java.sql.Date)] = [name: string, date: date]
```

Is there a way to select `Date` fields from `Dataset` without going to `DataFrame` and back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Been bashing my head against problems like these for the whole day. I think you can solve your problem with one line:

```
implicit val e: Encoder[(String, Date)] = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[(String,Date)]
```

At least that has been working for me.

## EDIT

In these cases, the problem is that for most `Dataset` operations, Spark 2 requires an `Encoder` that stores schema information (presumably for optimizations). The schema information takes the form of an implicit parameter (and a bunch of `Dataset` operations have this sort of implicit parameter).

In this case, the OP found the correct schema for `java.sql.Date` so the following works:

```
implicit val e = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.DATE
```

Comment: This did not directly solve the problem, but it got me on the right track. Using `implicit val encodeDate = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.DATE` solves the problem. I'm not sure why that is not handled by the default implicits.